# How can I take snapshot of Hbase cluster in a single snapshot not table wise?

Tags: hbase, snapshot

I want to take a single snapshot of my full Hbase cluster not different snapshot for each table

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots can only be taken for individual tables, however it sounds like what you really want to do is backup the cluster. If this is the case, then the approach you use to backup the entire cluster depends on if you need to keep the cluster live. If you do and you can't take individual snapshots of the tables, then I would recommend that you replicate the cluster. This replication can be to another HBase Cluster or even to a third party such as Amazon S3. HDP currently has a solution for incementally backing up a live cluster that is not yet ready for production systems. However, this is something to keep an eye on for the future. You can find more information about that [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_data-access/content/ch_hbase_bar.html). If the cluster can be shutdown, then you can stop HBase and run Distcp to copy the contents of the HBase directory in HDFS to either the same cluster in another directory, or to a different cluster.